# How can I pass the array of dictionaries from one tableview to another custom tableview in Swift

Tags: iphone, json, swift, uitableview

I fetch `Json` menu data in a tableview. Now I need to pass the `"Subcategory"` data to the another tableview at the time of custom cell creation. I took another tableview in the custom cell on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

**My json data format**

```
    [{ 
      "id" :"233",
      "name" :"dgghd",
      "subcategory:[{ 
                     "id" :"233",
                      "name" :"dgghd",
                      "items:[{ 
                                "id" :"233",
                                "name" :"dgghd",

                              },... more items]

                    },....more  subcategories
                   ]
       },....more main menus
      ]
```

**Fetching menu data**

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, myUrl)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
          //                        print(json)

                //main menu section

                    for (_, content) in json {

                        let menu = Menu(id: Int(content["id"].stringValue),
                                        name: content["name"].string,
                                        image: content["image"].string,
                                        coupon: content["coupon"].int,
                                        icon: content["icon"].string,
                                        order: Int(content["order"].stringValue),
                                        aname: content["name"].string,
                                        options: Int(content["options"].stringValue),
                                    subcategory:content["subcategory"].arrayObject)

                        self.menus.append(menu)
                    }

                  for (_, sub) in json {

                        for (_, subcategory) in sub["subcategory"] {

                            let subcategory = SubCategory(
                                id: Int(subcategory ["id"].stringValue),
                                name: subcategory ["name"].string,
                                description: subcategory ["description"].string,
                                image: subcategory ["image"].string,
                                coupon: Int(subcategory ["coupon"].stringValue),
                                icon: subcategory ["icon"].string,
                                order: Int(subcategory ["order"].stringValue),
                                aname: subcategory ["aname"].string,
                                options: Int(subcategory ["options"].stringValue),
                                items: subcategory ["items"].arrayObject
                            )

                            self.subcategories.append(subcategory)
                        }
```

**custom cell creation code**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menus.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Menucell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! MENUTableViewCell

    let menu: Menu = menus[indexPath.row]
    cell.Ordermenu.text! = menu.name!

    return cell
}
```

How can I pass the subcategory  to the custom "Menutableviewcell" so that I can display the subcategory data there into sections?

Answer (score 0):

If I 'm getting this right, you have created somewhere a class named SubCategory. If that's the case you could create a var with the type of SubCategory, optional, inside your custom cell and on creation of the cell you can pass the SubCategory that your received inside your custom cell and use it there as you like.

Your custom cell would be something like

```
class MENUTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var subCat: SubCategory?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

      super.init(frame: frame)
      setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and when you create the cell would be something like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Menucell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! MENUTableViewCell

    cell.SubCategory = subcategories[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

you could do the same with your menu and that way you can pass all your data inside your cell and handle everything there.

Edit: You could use the didSet for the subCat var like this:

```
var subCat: subCategory? {
    didSet{

        if let name = subCategory?.name {
            nameLabel.text = name
        }else {
            nameLabel.text = "Some default text"
        }
}
```

this is the safer way so if the subCategory is nil your app won't crash and you can check your code further to see why it's nil.

Comment: but i am getting nil value in subCat when i am trying to display its value in  MENUTableViewCell  like this http://pastie.org/10909609

Comment: And in your code i think instead of cell.SubCategory.... cell.subCat  should be used because you have created subCat as SubCategory type

Comment: I edited my answer so you can use the didSet to safely unwrap the subCategory var you are passing and deal with it if it's nil. I guess you must check your code so when the cell is created you would have already received the json data.

Comment: its not working . please see this link if you can able to help here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433092